# Form Upload File to a Web API that Requires a Custom Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have a standard HTML form that asks the user for a file to upload.

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="http://localhost:5000/api/collection/csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
      <input type="file" name="files" multiple />                       
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This alone would work fine, however the API requires an Authorization Header that looks something like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhb.......
```

The web API is an ASP.Net Web API that is expecting the header, the content type `multipart/form-data`, and to have proper `webkit- boundary` as part of the POST submission.

I've searched online and it seems there's no way to add a custom header to a form submission. Is there another way to upload this file properly with the custom header?

Comment: If the API supports CORS, using Ajax with FormData is an option

Comment: This fixed it! I had some trouble with FormData and ajax initially but I needed `contentType: false, processData: false` which I did not have initially!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was what @Musa suggested in the comments.

I needed to use jQuery's form `submit` event so I can create a `FormData` object and submit that using ajax.

The solution in this case was this:

```
$("#uploadForm").on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this)[0];
    var postData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/collection/csv",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
          //ADD CUSTOM HEADER HERE
          request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + idToken);
        },
        data: postData,
        contentType: false, //THIS IS REQUIRED 
        processData: false, //THIS IS REQUIRED
        success: function(data){
          //Handle success here
          resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
           //Handle error
           reject(error);
        }
      });
});
```

I'm not sure why `contentType: false, processData: false` was required, but it wouldn't work without it.